# Validationerror in clean methods in Django forms not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a form that will make the user select at least one option from the radioselect. However my clean form methods are not working. I hope someone can spot where the issue is with my forms.validationerror method.

I tried to my form below

```
credit_choices = (
    ('100',  '100  credits - $10'),
    ('200',  '200  credits - $18 - 11% Savings'),
    ('500',  '500  credits - $40 - 25% Savings'),
    ('1000', '1000 credits - $70 - 43% Savings'),
    ('2000', '2000 credits - $120 - 67% Savings'),
)

class CreditForm(forms.Form):

    credit = forms.ChoiceField(
        label='Select Amount of Credits to Purchase',
        choices=credit_choices,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        required=True
        )
```

I also tried to clean the form suing the different variations of two methods. The clean_field() and the clean(). I was able to print "None" or the parameter that was chosen but the will skip the step of going into forms.Validationerror and go into Valueerror on the page.

```
def clean_credit(self):
    credit = self.cleaned_data.get("credit")
    print credit
    if credit == None:
        print "test"
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please choose one")
    return credit

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(CreditForm, self).clean()
    credit = self.cleaned_data.get("credit")
    print credit
    if not credit:
        print "test"
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please choose one")
    return cleaned_data
```

My view is in the attached below.

```
class AddCredits(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, TemplateView):
    form_class = CreditForm
    template_name = 'addcredit.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddCredits, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        user = self.request.user
        usercred = get_object_or_404(UserCredit, user=user)

        context["user_credit"] = usercred.credit
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            credit = form.cleaned_data.get("credit")
            request.session["credit"] = credit
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('CheckOut')
```

I completely have no idea why the function forms.validation is being skipped. Any helpful advice will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please, instead of `if credit == None:` do `if credit is None:`.

Comment: I tried that already, thats not working. As in it will still skip the forms.validationerror that is supposed to be raised.

Comment: Please provide full stack trace of the error

Comment: Not the problem, but you should definitely not be overriding `post` here. The only thing you are doing is setting the session value, and that should be done in `form_valid` itself.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman. I was looking at the wrong area(forms.py and validation) to fix for the last few days.

Answer (score 0):

After researching the form_valid method, I have identified that the issue wasn't on my validation or form.py. I should not be overriding the post method, the form_valid method should be used to get the posted data.

This below has the corrected view.py, instead of post, I swapped it with form_valid method to collect the posted data. This below works now.

```
class AddCredits(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'addcredit.html'
    form_class = CreditForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddCredits, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        user = self.request.user
        usercred = get_object_or_404(UserCredit, user=user)

        context["user_credit"] = usercred.credit
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        credit = form.cleaned_data.get("credit")
        self.request.session["credit"] = credit
        return super(AddCredits, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('CheckOut')
```

Comment: not correct. `form_valid` shouldn't call `form.is_valid`